# Which dependencies are required for a spring-boot maven rest application?

Tags: java, rest, maven

This is what I have at this point, and it works, but are there others I should have instead or in addition to:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I've noticed that some examples in tutorials show version, which I don't have any of.

Comment: To include version, go to https://mvnrepository.com and select the required repository and add that snippet. If your application is working with those dependencies, why would you need to add any others?

Comment: when your parent project is spring-boot-starter-parent, it includes the version and it manages versions of all spring dependencies. in such a case, you should not add version to each dependencies separately, as it might result in incompatible versions coming together, which would cause more problems.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. "This works, what do I need to make it work?" (Although specifying `spring-boot-starter` is almost certainly redundant.) You *should* pin to a version at the top level to avoid undue complication(s), though.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read the docs which have examples like that: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Comment: @DaveNewton sometimes things work at first, but because they weren't setup correctly, it causes issues over time.  This is what I was asking, since this is a very basic app, was just looking for validation for correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.springboot.testapplication</groupId>
<artifactId>testapplication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>testapplication</name>
<description>Spring Boot Application</description>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```